# Mounting an iSCSI Server in a WinPE Instance

Tags: services, iscsi, winpe

Does anybody know of a Small-and-Light iSCSI Server
that I can use in WinPE (Windows 10 based PE)
to mount a target for a remote client?

Better...
is there a way to use the MS-ISCSI server in WinPE

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting, however, I assume it is possible. I am not sure if MS iSCSI Target work under WinPE. You can use alternatives, e.g. StarWind VSAN free might work.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free
You will need to install it on full Windows installation and copy it files to WinPE environment. I am still not sure that it will work, worth testing.

Comment: Hi @stuka... I fount on gitHub a funcional user-mode ISCSI server from Tal Aloni... Works fine in Windows 10 (depends on .net 3.5 though)...  and I found a old download from Microsoft of a Windows 2008R2 iSCSI server install... when I have some time I will try use both of them in Windows PE... but I would rather a solution reling on more recent Windows Server (2016/2019)...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It would be great to hear your results. Interesting how this setup will work.

Comment: iSCSIConsole from Tal Aloni works fine as a target server in Windows 10... 
When I have some free time and opportunity I will test it in a WinPE/RE made from a Windows 10 source (WinPESE and WinXPE is what I'm currently using)...
If I cant find a better solution... I will also try to snatch the binaries from Server2008R2-Target install and apply to windows 10 (not very confident in this one tough)